# TypeError: Cannot read property 'wanted' of undefined:

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have been deploying functions with firebase successfully all day learning how to use it. I was trying to see what happened if I initialized another directory that deploys to the same project and had no problems until i updated my npm version and now I am getting "Unexpected error has occurred" whenever I try to deploy

I have tried updating npm permission by making my own user the owner of the node_modules, bin, and share directories. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling firebase-tools. I have also tried deleting all my current function directories and initializing a fresh directory and reinstalling my dependencies in there fresh.

Here is the debug log

```
Dylans-MacBook-Pro-3:functions dsenderling$ firebase deploy --debug
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.526Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.528Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --debug
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.529Z] CLI Version:   7.0.2
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.529Z] Platform:      darwin
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.529Z] Node Version:  v10.16.0
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.529Z] Time:          Wed Jul 03 2019 13:04:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.529Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-07-03T18:04:35.537Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.537Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.537Z] [iam] checking project my-awesome-project-5a4e9 for permissions ["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","firebase.projects.get"]
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.539Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-awesome-project-5a4e9:testIamPermissions  
 permissions=[cloudfunctions.functions.create, cloudfunctions.functions.delete, cloudfunctions.functions.get, cloudfunctions.functions.list, cloudfunctions.functions.update, cloudfunctions.operations.get, firebase.projects.get]
[2019-07-03T18:04:35.769Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Wed, 03 Jul 2019 18:04:35 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, server-timing=gfet4t7; dur=83, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39", accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
[2019-07-03T18:04:37.033Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'wanted' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js:37:51
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

My gut tells me there is something wrong with firebase-tools or my firebase sdk but I can't figure out what. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have looked through quite a few posts about similar looking TypeErrors but unfortunately I have been unable to find any that seemed to be occurring for the same reason as mine. The things I have tried already to fix my problem largely come from other posts here.

Comment: try to updated f`firebase-tools` to 7.1.1, it worked for me

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Had the exact same problem, started right after updating npm from 6.9.2 to 6.10.0.

Ended up downgrading back to 6.9.2 (npm install -g npm@6.9.2), and my firebase deploys started working again, right away.

Edit : firebase deploys are working with npm 6.10.1, safe to update now!

Comment: Thank's very so much man, i am very angry trying to fixed that problem

Answer (score 8):

I think this issue is caused by a fix in npm 6.10.0, see https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/176.

A workaround is to modify `/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js` (linux).
For macOS and nvm, see comments below.

from:

```
if (!output) {
  return;
}
```

to:

```
if (!output || !output["firebase-functions"]) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Just tried this on lines 36-38 and I am getting npm ERR! missing script: lint.

Comment: @dsenderling Hmmm strange. Can you gist your file?

Comment: I noticed that your formating is wrong. You have line-breaks at line24,26. Those should not be there. Did you add those? This is how is should look (without the workaround) https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/v7.0.2/src/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js

Comment: Thanks for trying, hopefully google comes out with a fix soon, or I might try reverting to an older version of npm to see if that helps or something

Comment: or try to remove / install firebase-tools, then apply the fix again?

Comment: Those line breaks were left over from me testing the solution that @aaronvargas left. I removed the line breaks and tried again but it didn't help any.

Comment: just tried removing firebase-tools globally and reinstalling globally and trying the fix again and no dice

Comment: Sad to hear. Then downgrading npm is probably the thing to do.

Comment: The path in macOS is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js`.

Comment: if you use nvm the file path is like `<user_home>/.nvm/versions/node/v11.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js`

Answer (score 1):

This just started happening to me also...

Looks like either `npm` is outputting a different result for this command

```
npm outdated firebase-functions --json=true
// for me outputs  {}\n
```

And the script `checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js` is expecting something like this (which it would get if your firebase-functions WAS actually out of date)

```
{
  "current": "2.5.0",
  "wanted": "2.5.0",
  "latest": "3.0.2",
  "location": "node_modules/some path /firebase-functions"
}
```

OR a blank output... more likely in your case

**What you can do to 'Fix' it**

This will probably get fixed pretty soon as it start affecting more people...
for now
modify 
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js`

add this to account for the updated empty output of `{}\n` around line 24

```
            if (data && data.toString() !== "{}\n") {
                output = JSON.parse(data.toString("utf8")); // existing Code!
            }
```

Not sure how the update process works for npm, so you might have to revert this to update it when fixed, but I don't think so.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried editing that file and now i'm getting a missing script: lint error. It's progress at least. I am new to javascript so I will post the line I edited in case I made a mistake. I ran npm outdated firebase-functions --json=true and got back {}. Also sorry for the bad formatting in this comment I am new to this site and I am having trouble making it pretty child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
                 if (data && data.toString() !== "{}\n") {
                output = JSON.parse(data.toString("utf8")); // existing Code!
            }
            });

Comment: It's safer for now to just roll back to previous npm version > npm install -g npm@6.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with npm@6.12.0 and firebase-functions@3.3.0.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'wanted' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js:37:51
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Fixed by changing in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js` line #37.

```js
var wanted = (output["firebase-functions"] || {}).wanted;
var latest = (output["firebase-functions"] || {}).latest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of old version of Firebase CLI on mac, tried to update using the standard command npm command ==> `npm install -g firebase-tools` wasn't helpful as it showed that my CLI was updated but deploying function command was picking an old cached version so what worked for me is to use **automatic install script** to upgrade to the latest version: -

`curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`

More details can be found on the official doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#macos)